# Why is there a delay in Actual Permissions when adding a user to a SharePoint group with CSOM

Tags: permissions, client-object-model, groups

I have site that has unique permissions.

I have a SharePoint group that has permissions for that site.

If I add a user to the SharePoint group through the SharePoint UI, the user can immediately get to the site.

If I remove the user from the SharePoint group through the SharePoint UI, the user immediately loses access.

This is terrific.

**However, when I use CSOM to add the user to the Group, I can see the user has been added to the group if I look at the group membership, but the user does not have immediate access to the site.** **I do believe that eventually the user does gain access to the site, but I can not predict when that happens.
Can anyone explain why this is? Or at least validate that this is true?**

(It also appears that removing the user from the group with CSOM immediately removes the user's access.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that my environment allows both Claims and Forms authentication.

Because of this, it is necessary to convert a LoginName to a WindowsClaim. I did this by hardcoding "i:0#.w|" to the start of the LoginName and everything worked.

I don't know if this string is the same for everyone, but you can find it by looking at the details of a user that was added via the UI.

This took me way too long to figure out.